# Rspec for retry mechanism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm using faraday and i have implemented a retry mechanism which is working as expected but i don't understand how can i test it on rspec.

Below is my retry mechanism:

```
def perform(url:)
  max_retries = 3
  retry_count = 0
  delay = 1

  begin
    req = config_faraday
    response = req.get(url)
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  rescue Faraday::Error => err
    puts "Request failed. Retries left: #{max_retries - retry_count}"
    sleep delay += retry_count
    retry_count += 1
    retry if retry_count < max_retries
  ensure
    if retry_count == max_retries
      raise ApiError.new("Number of retries has been exhausted")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to handle the case of `when api is not working`

I have written it by stubbing the `get` request and making the `retry_count` to max and then trying to hit the request:

```
  context 'Api is not working' do

    let(:retry_count){
      3
    }

    before do
      request = double(Faraday)
      allow(request).to receive(:get).and_raise(Faraday::Error)
    end

    it "raise error after retries" do
      expect(Products::Fetcher.perform(url: url)).to raise_error(Products::ApiError)
    end
  end
```

But i'm getting an error:

```
 Products::Fetcher Api is not working raise error after retries
     Failure/Error: expect(Products::Fetcher.perform(url: url)).to raise_error(Products::ApiError)
       expected Products::ApiError but was not given a block
     # ./spec/services/products/fetcher_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird: your tests as such do not test any of the code of the `perform`. Which is sometimes good, but in this case they do not seem to test anything other than your stub.

For API testing I would suggest looking at a gem like vcr. But this would not work to reproduce the failing, then retrying and then succeeding.

To test that, from the code you showed, I would stub `config_faraday` to return a mock object, that would raise an error two times when `get` is called and return a body on the third time, for instance.

Comment: Can you write code of your example? I m not that good in rspec

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax for `raise_error` matcher
Correct is:

```
expect { raise StandardError }.to raise_error
```

Your example:

```
expect(Products::Fetcher.perform(url: url)).to raise_error(Products::ApiError)
```

So correct form should be:

```
expect{ Products::Fetcher.perform(url: url) }.to raise_error(Products::ApiError)
```